# Até que ponto posso usar os dados do Instagram num crawler?

Tags: python

Eu sou apenas curiosa, mas esses dias o Instagram tem me gerado certas dúvidas. Já fiz um crawler simples usando BeautifulSoup pra extrair data e receber diariamente informações de novas postagens. A questão é se eu posso extrair informações de acesso ao meu perfil? Quantas vezes um usuário x visualizou, quantas vezes um usuário x buscou meu user. Eu li todo o termo de segurança deles e sei que eles guardam esse tipo de informação, mas é possível EU ter esse tipo de acesso ou é algo restrito deles? Desculpem a dúvida "simples".

Comment: Usando a `API` deles e com autorização do usuário você provavelmente pode acessar todas as informações que forem públicas: https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Answer (score 0):

Se as informações não são públicas (ou você não tem acesso depois de fazer login), não é possível fazer scraping delas. Às vezes as informações são carregadas mas não mostradas; daí, uma análise das requisições que vão e vêm e dos elementos ocultos da página pode revelar alguma coisa, mas acredito que não haja nada assim com o Instagram.

Fora crawlers, pode-se dar uma olhada na [API do Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) como mencionado no comentário do @Sorack, mas não encontrei nada parecido ao que você quer; provavelmente é algo que eles não disponibilizam.